# What does using a ForwardIterator, as opposed to a BidirectionalIterator, do at the hardware level?

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization, iterator

Let's say that I have a container and I need to move through its elements 1-by-1. If I know I only need to use the `++` operator on the iterator, I should use a `ForwardIterator`, but what do I lose in terms of performance if I use a `BidirectionalIterator` instead? I don't understand how telling the compiler that you're restricting the direction of the iterator within a certain scope can help it make your program better.

Comment: Read the generated assembler code, that's as close to the hardware you will be able to get. However I don't think that's really what you are after, instead I think you want to know how the compiler could recognize an iterator that only moves in one direction, and the answer to that is basically that it only have an operator for that direction.

Comment: This has more to do with the underlying type requirements. Using a Bidirectional when is not needed may unnecessarily require backward iteration on a type that does not implement it.

Comment: It's all about algorithm design, not efficiency. If you use a forward iterator you can pass a stream to the function, but not if it's bidirectional.

Comment: I don't see any performance loss but I see readability benefits. You say what you exactly need and what you mean to do and what may happen.

Comment: ForwardIterator and BidirectionalIterator are just concepts, not classes or templates. You "tell the compiler" that you are using a forward iterator, as opposed to a bidirectional one, by *not* invoking the `--` operator on it. There is little the compiler can do with this "information".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of the iterator describes what operations you are allowed to use on it.  An iterator itself is just a concept to describe a type pointer that is used to interact with standard containers.

A forward iterator can only be incremented.  A bidirectional iterator supports everything a forward iterator does and can be decremented.  A random access iterator supports everything a bidirectional iterator does and it can be supports arithmetic operations like a pointer.  There is a nice little chart [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/) that shows you everything the different "types" support.

Knowing what these types support allows you to use these types as template parameters to express to the end user what type of iterator you function needs.  If a function calls for a random access iterator you shouldn't give it a forward iterator because more than likely they are doing operations on the iterator that the forward iterator can't do.  Conversely if you have a function that expects a forward iterator and you pass it a random access iterator then you are fine since a random access iterator supports all forward iterator operation.